# How to implement a tree structure, but still be able to reference it as a flat array by index?

Tags: c#, tree

I want to have a tree in memory, where each node can have multiple children. I would also need to reference this tree as a flat structure by index. for example:

```
    a1
       b1
       b2
       b3
    c1
       d1
          e1
          e2
       d2
          f1
```

Would be represented as a flat structure as I laid out (i.e.; a1=0, b1=1, d1=5, etc..)

Ideally I would want lookup by index to be O(1), and support insert, add, remove, etc.. with a bonus of it being threadsafe, but if that is not possible, let me know.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is useful when using a tree - could you let us know how you're using it? You may just be able to store a reference to the node under which you want to insert it.

Comment: Specifically, why do you want to lookup a tree by index - it seems quite meaningless, since the nature of a tree does away with indices altogether.

Comment: Indeed, if you can describe what you're using it for, it might be possible to make a suggestion as to an appropriate way to handle it. Specifically, you can trade access time for modification time in many cases.

Comment: The structure is represented in memory as a tree (non-binary). I want to display this in a DataGridView, so I am implementing VirtualMode for the control and providing data from the tree. DataGridView VirtualMode requests information in RowIndex and ColumnIndex format, so I need to be able to lookup information in that manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a reasonably balanced tree, you can get indexed references in O(log n) time - just store in each node a count of the number of nodes under it, and update the counts along the path to a modified leaf when you do inserts, deletions, etc.  Then you can compute an indexed access by looking at the node counts on each child when you descend from the root.  How important is it to you that indexed references be O(1) instead of O(log n)?

If modifications are infrequent with respect to accesses, you could compute a side vector of pointers to nodes when you are finished with a set of modifications, by doing a tree traversal.  Then you could get O(1) access to individual nodes by referencing the side vector, until the next time you modify the tree.  The cost is that you have to do an O(n) tree traversal after doing modifications before you can get back to O(1) node lookups.  Is your access pattern such that this would be a good tradeoff for you?

Comment: My first suggestion is generalized in Mark Chu-Carrol's article on finger trees: http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2009/05/finally_finger_trees.php

Answer (score 1):

I use something similar to this in a Generic Red-Black tree I use. Essentially to start you need a wrapper class like Tree, which contains the actual nodes.

This is based on being able to reference the tree by index

So you can do something like the following to set up a tree with a Key, Value

```
class Tree<K, V>
{
    //constructors and any methods you need

    //Access the Tree like an array
    public V this[K key]
    {
        get {
            //This works just like a getter or setter
            return SearchForValue(key);
        }
        set {
            //like a setter, you can use value for the value given
            if(SearchForValue(key) == null)
            {
                // node for index doesn't exist, add it
                AddValue(key, value);
            } else { /* node at index already exists... do something */ }
     }
}
```

This works on the assumption that you already know how to create a tree, but want to to able to do stuff like access the tree by index. Now you can do something like so:

```
Tree<string,string> t = new Tree<string,string>();
t["a"] = "Hello World";
t["b"] = "Something else";
Console.Writeline("t at a is: {0}", t["a"]);
```

Finally, for thread saftety, you can add an object to you're Tree class and on any method exposed to the outside world simply call

```
Lock(threadsafetyobject) { /*Code you're protecting */ }
```

Finally, if you want something cooler for threadsafety, I use an object in my tree call a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) that allows multiple reads, but locks down when you want to do a write, which is especially importantif you're changing the tree's structure like doing a rotation whilst another thread is trying to do a read.

One last thing, i rewrote the code to do this from memory, so it may not compile, but it should be close :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a defined number of children for each tree (for instance, a [Binary Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Tree#Methods_for_storing_binary_trees)), then it's not too difficult (although you potentially waste a lot of space).

If it has a variable number of children, you'd probably have to come up with some convoluted manner of storing the index of a node's first child.

I'm not seeing how it would be useful to do this, though. The point of trees is to be able to store and retrieve items below a particular node. If you want constant-time look-up by index, it doesn't sound like you want a tree at all. By storing it in an array, you have to consider the fact that if you add an element into the middle, all of the indexes you had originally stored will be invalid.

However, if indeed you want a tree, and you still want Constant Time insertion/lookup, just store a reference to the parent node in a variable, and then insert the child below it. That *is* constant time.

Comment: No defined number of children :(

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a little work, but your insert and remove methods will become much more costly. To keep the array properly ordered, you will need to shift large chunks of data to create or fill space. The only apparent advantage is very fast traversal (minimal cache misses).

Anyhow, one solution is to store the number of children in each node, like so:

```
struct TreeNode
{
    int numChildren;
    /* whatever data you like */
};
```

Here's an example of how to traverse the tree...

```
TreeNode* example(TreeNode* p)
{
    /* do something interesting with p */

    int numChildren = p->numChildren;
    ++p;
    for(int child = 1; child <= numChildren; ++child)
       p = example(p);
    return p;
}
```

Hopefully you can derive insert, remove, etc... on your own.

:)

Answer (score 0):

You could always look at using [Joe Celko's](http://www.celko.com/) technique of using [Nested Sets to represent trees](http://www.intelligententerprise.com/001020/celko.jhtml). He's Sql focused, but the parallels are there between nested sets and representing a tree as a flat array, and it may be useful for your ultimate reason for wanting to use an array in the first place.

As others note though, most of the time it's easier just to traverse the tree directly as linked nodes. The oft-cited array implementation of a tree is a Binary Search Tree because for a node `n`, the parent is `(n-1)/2`, the left child is `2n+1` and the right child is `2n+2`

The downside of using arrays are insertions, deletions, pruning and grafting all (usually) require the array to be modified when the tree changes.

You could also read up on [B-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is good. But a flat array can be addressed as a binary tree by calculating the tree level as a power and then adding the offset. But this only works if the tree is a binary one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for binary tree that you don't have to index any. The solution might be updated to non binary tree if each node has exact number of children
The complexity is θ(h) where h is height of the tree
[How to insert delete or update a value of binary tree by index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68466600/how-to-insert-delete-or-update-a-value-of-binary-tree-by-index/68466601#68466601)